# How to crop text (with an ellipsis) at the end of container

Tags: html, css

I want to crop a text at the end of a container but not at the end of a line using css. Here is an example of what I want
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9x1q.png)

**Edit**: What I already tried

```
overflow: hidden; <- to hide the overflowing text
white-space: nowrap; <- seems to be necessary but also seems to be part of the problem
text-overflow: ellipsis; <- should crop the text
```

[Example of the current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHq0h.png)

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Comment: show httml please

Comment: @Temani Afif no its not duplicate since i already tried that one.

Comment: and in that question you will find the best you can do for such thing ;) ... check all the answers and comments, all the tricks are there including JS one since CSS is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called Line Clamping and it's available only in WebKit rendering engine. You just need to use the following CSS for the element that needs to get clamped at the end.

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

Here, the value `3` is the number of lines you want to show before the clamping happens. An example to demonstrate the effect here:

```css
p {
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p>
  WebKit Browsers will clamp the number of lines 
  in this paragraph to 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis 
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

**References:**

- [`-webkit-line-clamp` · dropshado.ws](http://dropshado.ws/post/1015351370/webkit-line-clamp)
- [`line-clamp` | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)
- [Line Clampin' (Truncating Multiple Line Text) | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)
- [CSS Line-Clamp — The Good, the Bad and the Straight-up Broken](https://medium.com/mofed/css-line-clamp-the-good-the-bad-and-the-straight-up-broken-865413f16e5)

> **Note:** None of the above links are mine. `:)`

Comment: And what if i dont know the amount of lines i got? i included a screenshot in the question.

Comment: @RaZor1994 You don't need to know how many lines you have got, but you just need to know how many lines you wanna display.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Sorry for the wrong gender, but did you find the snippet with HTML and CSS and there's Run code snippet in the other guy's post? There was `<div class="text">Lorem ipsum do...` `:)`

Comment: can i have a dynamic amount of lines to show?

Comment: @RaZor1994 Ah... Not possible as of today... No. You might need to use JavaScript based solution for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RaZor1994 You are welcome! `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar hoo i ask from op to show his html (how ask the question) because he worte a comment to the guy that post the answer...

Comment: @לבנימלכה I was talking about your comment `show HTML please` in the answerer's post.

Comment: fine all good have a nice day

Comment: @לבנימלכה Hey, sorry for the miscommunication... `:(`